# Widget configuration for enum pop-up

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

How do I configure the widget so that when I click a parameter, a pop-up shows up below with different cases like in the picture here (Ship and the other options)?

[image]

I think the parameter should be an enum, but I only get a pop-up like this (I have tried a lot of different combinations):
[image]

My configuration:
[image]